# How can I display the grand total in the minicart? - Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, tax, mini-cart, totals

I currently have my subtotal tax settings set to 'Display subtotal excluding tax'. This has changed the subtotal in the minicart to display the subtotal excluding tax.

[image]

**How can I display the grand total of the order including tax in the highlighted area with the settings mentioned above?**

Comment: Did you reach an answer for this? Grand total would include shipping?

Answer (score 2):

This may be late, but I would post this for the people who reach here in future.

Let's start with the layout.xml
[scope]/[module]/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="common.checkout.config"
               template="[scope]_[module]::checkout/config.phtml" cacheable="false">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Total Cost with GST</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> I am not sure if it is a good idea to place cacheable="false" block in a default.xml, Better to try without it and thoroughly test.

Override the and add getQuote Method.
[scope]/[module]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" type="IWD\Opc\Block\Onepage" />
```

app/code/[scope]/[module]/Block/Onepage.php

```
namespace [scope]\[module]\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage as CheckoutOnepage;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider;

class Onepage extends CheckoutOnepage
{

    public $checkoutSession;
    public $quote = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        CompositeConfigProvider $configProvider,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        array $layoutProcessors = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $formKey, $configProvider, $layoutProcessors, $data);
    }

    public function getQuote()
    {
        if (null === $this->quote) {
            $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }

        return $this->quote;
    }
}
```

[scope]/[module]/view/frontend/templates/checkout/config.phtml

> Those who need the explanation, why below two code blocks are needed please check at the end of the post.

```
<?php if($block->getQuote() && $block->getQuote()->getId()):?>
<script>
window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
// Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

In [scope]/[module]/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="common.checkout.config" remove="true"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Finaly let's add them to the mini-cart
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/[scope]_[module]/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

```
<div id="grand-total" class="grand-total" data-bind="scope:'grand-total'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#grand-total": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
        }
</script>
```

The explanation for adding window.checkoutConfig

> When loading vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/grand-total.js (By Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total entry in the default.xml layout file ), It also tries to load the vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/quote.js (By the 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote' in the requireJs define array). However, when loading the quote.js it tries to access certain data in the window.checkoutConfig. This is not available in the pages except checkout control actions. So we have to manually place this on every page with the help of default.xml.
>
> I don't agree with this Magento core implementation as I believe, this should be implemented with the use of customerData with the local storage. You may find more details regarding the issue with this Magento Core approach, in [this](https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-20-do-not-depend-on-window-checkoutconfig) article by Jisse Reitsma

Comment: why we removed the block from checkout_index_index.xml ?

Comment: Because the same block added to the content area in [scope]/[module]/view/frontend/layout/default.xml, This is to avoid having duplicate sections.
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="common.checkout.config"
               template="[scope]_[module]::checkout/config.phtml" cacheable="false">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, just an idea

You could extend **module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** & replace **subtotal** (or create a new) component with your needings

```
<item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

More info about **uiComponents** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_xmldeclaration_concept.html

An alternate, and easier, way if you are not comfortable with UI Components (easy!) would be deleting that component in your layout extend & then just print your wanted value in **Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml** template (overwriting the template in your custom theme, of course)

```
<?php echo $block->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); ?>
```

This should work, as **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar** (which is the associated block of minicart template) extends **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart**, which provides `getQuote()` method

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but I'm going to leave my solution in here also.
The idea is to display the grand total in the minicart in the same way the subtotal is displayed.

Let's make a new module called `Easylife_Checkout` with these files

`registration.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Easylife_Checkout', __DIR__);
```

`composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "easylife/module-checkout",
    "description": "Display the grand total in minicart",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "*",
        "magento/module-checkout": "*",
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Easylife\\Checkout\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

`README.md` - explain here what the module does - you can even link to this answer :).

`etc/module.xml` - the module sequence file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Easylife_Checkout">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

So far so good

The problem is that you don't have the grand total available in the data source that returns the subtotal, `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart` class.
So let's add it via a plugin

`etc/di.xml` - dependency injection file where we declare the plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="get-grand-total" type="Easylife\Checkout\Plugin\CustomerData\CartPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`Plugin/CustomerData/CartPlugin.php` - the actual plugin. this makes the grand total available in the minicart data source

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Easylife\Checkout\Plugin\CustomerData;

use Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data as CheckoutHelper;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class CartPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var CheckoutHelper
     */
    private $checkoutHelper;
    /**
     * @var Quote
     */
    private $quote;

    /**
     * CartPlugin constructor.
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param CheckoutHelper $checkoutHelper
     */
    public function __construct(Session $checkoutSession, CheckoutHelper $checkoutHelper)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Cart $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterGetSectionData(Cart $subject, array $data)
    {
        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
        $data['grandTotalAmount'] = $totals['grand_total'] ? $totals['grand_total']->getData('value') : null;
        $data['grandTotal'] = $data['grandTotalAmount']
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($data['grandTotalAmount'])
            : 0;
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return Quote
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function getQuote()
    {
        if (null === $this->quote) {
            $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->quote;
    }
}
```

now we need a KO template to display the grand total.

`view/frontend/web/template/minicart/grand-total.html`

```
<div class="grand-total">
    <span class="label">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Order Total' -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <div class="amount price-container">
        <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().grandTotal"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

We don't need js component to render this template because we can use the same component that displays subtotal

Now let's add that component to the minicart.

`view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="minicart" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Easylife_Checkout/minicart/grand-total</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="subtotal"><!-- This will remove the subtotal. You can remove this if you want to keep it -->
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Do the usual `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the module `bin/magento setup:static-content deploy -f` to deploy the static resource.
That's it.

Comment: getting this error after following all above steps.

Element 'item': The type definition is abstract.

Comment: try replacing `<item name="subtotal">` with `<item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">`

Comment: @Marius i tried your module and it working well but i found one issue for showing grand total excluding tax can you help in this case.

Comment: I didn't try it for all tax configurations. You can try to see what you have available in `$this->getQuote()->getTotals();` inside the `afterGetSectionData` method.